# PuTTY Network Error: Connection timed out

Tags: putty, raspberry-pi

.Hey, 
so I used PuTTY to connect to my Raspberry Pi for over a year now and everything works fine. However, I now tried to connect to it at my workplace (the pi is still at home) and I suddenly can't seem to establish a connection, I just get an error message saying "Network error: Connection timed out".
 looked it up online and all I could find was to make sure the server I'm trying to connect to is running (it is). I also made sure PuTTY isn't being blocked by my academies network, which it isn't.

I then tried using an app on my phone to connect to the Pi and this is where it get's weird. Whenever I'm logged into my wifi at home, it works without problem, but as soon as I'm using my data or use any other wifi, it doesn't. I can't seem to find any solution for this, so I asked on stackoverflow but was told to repost it here.
If you need any other info just ask for it ^^

Thanks, Aci

Comment: Are you sure the academy network is not blocking the source and/or destination port to the device?

Comment: Yes, since it also doesn't work on my phone when using mobile data or other networks

Comment: Do you happen to use an xfinity AP for the pi?

Comment: I don't think so, I don't even know what that is though.

Comment: It's a brand of router that tends to filter traffic that is unusual for broadband connections

Comment: No, I don't think so